# SICP exercise 3.13 - make-cycle

Tags: linked-list, scheme, lisp, sicp, recursive-datastructures

I am doing [exercise 3.13 from SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node61.html) but I am unsure of my answer.

> Exercise 3.13: Consider the following make-cycle procedure, which uses
>   the last-pair procedure defined in Exercise 3.12:
>
> (define (make-cycle x)   (set-cdr! (last-pair x) x)   x)
>
> Draw a box-and-pointer diagram that shows the structure z created by
>
> (define z (make-cycle (list 'a 'b 'c)))
>
> What happens if we try to compute (last-pair z)?

I'm trying to understand why

```
(last-pair z)
```

becomes an infinite loop. Ignoring the box-and-pointer diagram, here is how I understand it:

```
(set-cdr! (last-pair x) x)
```

`(last-pair x)` would be the pair `(cons 'c '())`, then when we do `set-cdr!` the pair would become:

```
(cons 'c (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c ...))))))))))
```

is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Your answer appears to indicate that `(last-pair x)` is the result of calling `cons` infinitely many times.

Not so.

`x` is *still* just 3 cons cells, but the last one points to the first one, creating a **loop** (a snake biting itself on the tail).